# returning array from a COM developed in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, com

I have to return two dimensional array (can be two dimensional strings) from a COM developed in C#. This COM will be used in browser(javascript) and an ERP product called Unison. I am able to return simple types like string , int succesfully but not able to do it with arrays. As I am new to this COM, not sure if I have to specify any attributes to returntypes to work properly.

I have something like MarshalAs and safearrays. I didn't get these things exaclty.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sveerap

Comment: What version of the CLR are you using? If it's 4 then you can in theory write browser extensions in C#. If it's not, then you're potentially in trouble if someone else has the same idea as you. Versions 1 and 2 of the CLR could not coexist in the same process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to attribute your C# method with something like this...

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType=VarEnum.VT_BSTR)]
```

Note that VT_BSTR indicates there are strings in your array, check the VarEnum type for other possibilities.